# How does a projection Matrix work?

Tags: opengl, matrix, 3d

I have to write a paper for my A-Levels about 3D-Programming. But I got a serious problem understanding the **perspective projection Matrix** and I need to fully explain the Matrix in detail. I've searched a lot of websites and youtube videos on this topic but very little even try to answer the question **why** the Matrix has these values at that place. Based on this http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html I was able to find out how the w-row works, but I don't understand the other three.

I decided to use the "simpler" version for symmetric viewports only (right-handed Coord.):

[image: ![<code>r+l=0,</code>r-l=2r<code>(width);</code>t+b=0<code>,</code>t-b=2t<code>(height);</code>[n/r 0 0 0; 0 n/t 0 0; 0 0 -(f+n)/(f-n) -(2fn)/(f-n); 0 0 -1 0]`[1]]

I am very thankful for every attempt to explain the first three rows to me!

Comment: Before somebody downvotes it, this is actually a good question. I don't have the time right now to write a fledged out answer, but here's the gist of it: In 2D imagine a line parallel to the x axis at some distance y = n going from x = l…r ; this is the near projection "line". Now find a mapping that maps points on this line to the range -1…1 and a factor y_w and offset w_w to multiply and add to the y coordinates so that for y = n => w = 1 and for anything different w gets proportional to y.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The core reason for the matrix is to map the 3D coordinates to a 2D plane and have more distant objects be smaller.

For just this a much simpler matrix suffices (assuming your camera is at origin and looking at the Z axis):

```
1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0
```

After multiplying with this matrix and then renormalizing the `w` coordinate you have exactly that. Each `x,y,z,1` point becomes `x/z,y/z,0,1`.

However there is no depth information (Z is 0 for all points) so a depth buffer/filter won't work. For that we can a a parameter to the matrix so the depth information remains available:

```
1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0
0 0 0 1
0 0 1 0
```

Now the resulting point contains the inverse depth in the Z coordinate. Each `x,y,z,1` point becomes `x/z,y/z,1/z,1`.

The extra parameters are the result of mapping the coordinates into the `(-1,-1,-1)` - `(1,1,1)` device box (the bounding box where if you are outside of it the point won't get drawn) using a scale and a translate.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Actually it's really simple if someone finally explains it to you in one sentence!

Comment: Took me a long time to realize this. When you say "After multiplying with this matrix and then renormalizing the w coordinate you have exactly that.", it is not implicit that that's what actually happens. 
Only on some random youtube video when the guy said "the hardware does this for you" did everything click. I was trying to figure out how I could get the matrix to divide these other coords by Z for soooo long.
Thank you, and hope my comment can help some fellow silly thinking people out there.

Comment: Wait- How does the Z coordinate of the 4D vector effect the other coordinates because the parts of the matrix that multiply with Z are all 0? @TrisT or anyone else, can you specifically comment exactly what the guy made you realize please. Thank you in advance!

Comment: @TheSmolCodar you mean in the first matrix? that matrix will transform x,y,z,1 into x,y,0,z. Then the graphics pipeline will divide by the last component. In the rendering the final z component is used for depth testing but with the first matrix all of them are 0 so the second matrix is needed